# Thinking sphinx doesn't start - “Failed to start searchd daemon”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

`rake ts:start` gives following error:

```
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /home/deploy/megratec/shared/log/production.searchd.log.
Failed to start searchd. Check the log files for more information.
```

Log contains:

```
[Sun Oct  2 13:35:38.507 2016] [ 4780] listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
[Sun Oct  2 13:35:38.507 2016] [ 4780] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying... 
 ... 
[Sun Oct  2 13:36:14.541 2016] [ 4780] FATAL: bind() failed on 127.0.0.1: Address already in use
[Sun Oct  2 13:36:14.543 2016] [ 4779] watchdog: main process 4780 exited cleanly (exit code 1), shutting down
```

`ps -efa` shows no searchd running.

SOS!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Found `searchd` with `ps -aux` (no idea why `ps -efa` did nit work)

2) killed it with `sudo service sphinxsearch stop` (`rake ts:stop` and killing `searchd` process manually did not work).

3) Finally, `rake ts:rebuild` brought sphinx back to life.